# Elasticsearch indexing the same data

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I have created a river in the following way:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test1/hello1/_meta' -d 
'{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tdb",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "",
        "sql" : "select * from test "

    }


}'
```

I have made get request:

`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/jdbc/_search?pretty&q=*'`

It indexes the data,but next time when I change the query in a different river:
`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/jdbc/_search?pretty&q=*'`

It displays the same indexed data as for the previous river.

Comment: @vaibhav mule : Thanks for editing the question. Answer for my question?(PS:I am sorrry.I dont know how to tag a name while commenting)

Comment: Your question is bit confusing. How you are creating `jdbc` index? Also what do you mean by `it displays the same indexed data` whereas your are hitting the same `-XGET` request. one more thing river command should contains `_river` like `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/test1/_meta' -d`

Comment: thanks a lot.And in the XGET request  is jdbc and _search compulsary? Referring to : curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/jdbc/_search?pretty&q=*'

Comment: Can you please let us know. Which version of Elasticsearch you are using and How you are creating river any reference will be great.

Comment: i am using 1.4.4 ES  and this is how i am creating the river:                           curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tdb",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "",
        "sql" : "select * from test LIMIT 0,191000"
    }
}'